# A function is blocking the all application from being used until it has been executed

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that is do a big operation, when I call it, it is impossible to do another operation.

I tried to use a delegate thinking that if I call me.begininvoke(new mydelegate( adressof myfunction)) it will let other part of the application accessible whiling it is being executed but it didn't work.

How can I do so that when I call the function(when it is being executed) other part of the application be accessible?

Comment: You need to run in a background thread.

Comment: What does this have to do with TFS? Are you using the TFS API?

Comment: Search the documentation (or this site) for BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Sorry for that TFS precision, It was a mistake in typing. I am not using TFS API. How can I do that? (Run it in a background thread)

Comment: I found how to put the function in background thread; but the problem is the function accesses some controls from the main thread so I put it in a delegate and call the delegate in the sub that I pass to the thread. Here is the part of the code sub callDelegate () me.beginInvoke( new dSub(addresseof save)) end sub the I pass that procedure to the thread : dim subthread as new system.threading.thread (addressof calldelegate)